# time series anomaly detection steps-model-tools

Tags: python, r, machine-learning

I will have a device which will measure for example the temperature values every specific time intervals.

I want to train a model to understand which values do not belong to "normal" values and if so, raise an alert.So, I want an anomaly time series detection model.

At first, I thought of using a clustering model (kmeans, hierarchical).So, in the beginning of time, I will have many alerts.Later, some clusters will be created and hopefully I will have a good model!

But, since I don't have any experience on this I want to ask if this approach is right or what other approaches exist.And what kind of tools should I use (either Python either R).

I have read many links and a few papers and I can see that some people do not suggest kmeans [do not use k means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131281/dynamic-time-warping-clustering).

Also, I am not sure how/if to use Dynamic Time Warping Clustering.

I read a paper [Clustering of Time Series Subsequences is Meaningless](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/meaningless.pdf) which states that under some conditions applying clustering is meaningless.

I also saw the [tsouliers package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsouliers/tsouliers.pdf) , the [twitter's anomaly detection](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection) but I am not sure as I said which approach/tools should I use.

Comment: Are you predicting for tropical or temperate climate?

Comment: @AdamQuek:This is just an example.Local temperatures.But , I may use other parameters as well in specific time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to get anomaly detection working. I started using ARMA model to solve this but they had lot of false positives. So I am trying to implement using PCA. Idea is to approximate the function using PCA components. I got this idea through this [link](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/rad-outlier-detection-on-big-data-d6b0494371cc). Hopefully this helps you. Will update to better answer when I implement this fully.

Comment: Thanks for the link.The problem is the implementation and relativity to other approaches.